# Showing that $f(x) = g(x)$ $\forall x$ if $f(r) = g(r)$ for all rationals $r$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Suppose that for all rational numbers $r$, $f(r) = g(r)$. Show that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Very neat problem.

Answer (score 5):

Strategy:

Consider $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.  As the difference of two continuous functions, it is continuous.  It is zero on all the rationals.  You need to prove using continuity that is is also zero on the irrationals.

Comment: Details: Suppose $f(r) = c>0$ for some $r\in \mathbb{R}$, then by continuity of $f$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x\in (r-\delta, r+\delta), \ |f(r) - f(x)|<c$, i.e. $f(x)>0$ on that interval, which contradicts the fact that all the rationals on that interval evaluates to zero.

Comment: Did you mean "Suppose $h(r) = c > 0$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are seeking hints or a full solution, but here is a sketch (I can fill in more details if you need):

1. Note that rationals are **dense** in reals.  So, for every real number $r$ there exists a sequence of rational numbers $\{q_k\}$ such that $\lim_{k\to \infty} q_k = r$.
2. Now, use the fact that continuous means this in the language of sequences: if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, then for any sequence $x_k\to x$ as $k\to \infty$, we have $f(x_k)\to f(x)$ as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: I was looking for a full solution, if you don't mind. I'm reviewing for a midterm exam.

Comment: Answer by vadim123 is nice.  I wrote it out in detail as a comment.